# How to get the relative position of a point in a svg element?

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm creating a web application where is a svg element. In my Javascript code, I stored the svg container in a variable named "mySVG".

How can I get the pointer relative position to the svg element, I mean, X and Y position relative to the Top-Left corner of the svg element, using Javascript so I could display this data on screen while the user performs an action like click over a specific point in the svg container?

Comment: You're looking for `event.offsetX` and `event.offsetY` of a DOM event, which are meant to report mouse coordinates of an event relative to the target that triggered it (i.e. your svg container). This has typically had very poor support in browsers (FF for example doesn't even support said properties). You will always have better luck calculating relative coordinates by taking the absolute coordinates of the event and subtracting the [possibly static] coordinates of your svg container. Do you expect your svg container to ever move/shift?

Comment: The response helped me a lot. Thank you. And yes, if the window is resized, I need that the svg container moves so it can be adjusted to the current size.

Comment: To be clear, do you want the offset in pixels (screen space) or SVG units? If the latter, do you want it in units of the SVG root, or (if you are talking about some element within a transformed hierarchy) the offset with respect to the element itself?

Comment: I'd like to get it in pixels.